# various types of civibooking confirmation mail based on booking status

Tags: civibooking

It will be great to have the possibility to send various types of civibooking confirmation mail based on booking status. Each status requires a certain approach of communication. Can our experts here advise how I can use the IF and ELSE in combination of $booking_status to modify the current booking system template? Thx.